# changing android progress bar color

Tags: android, progress-bar

I'm looking for simple way to change the progress bar color.
I saw that its possible to add the attribute `android:indeterminateTint` and `android:indeterminateTintMode` for selecting color, but it available from API 21+.

Also creating custom selector is option - but still pretty complicated.

Are there simpler way that working prior to API 21 ?

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me.
Progress.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.MULTIPLY);

Answer (score 0):

One solution is simple as changing `colorAccent` value in colors.xml to the color you want.

Answer (score 0):

For a horizontal ProgressBar, you can use a `ColorFilter`:

```
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
    Color.RED, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```